# Centering a title under the x-axis of a pgfplot while ignoring the horizontal space occupied by the label for the plot

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I have the plot of a rational function, and I have the label for it on the right side.  I code the option `clip=false` to allow the label to extend "outside the Cartesian plane."  I want the label for the plot to be centered with respect to the `x`-axis.  Right now, it is displayed with respect the the width occupied by the `x`-axis and the label for the plot.

```
\documentclass[10pt]{amsart}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,intersections,}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.11}


\usepackage{mathtools,array}


\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[width=3in, height=3in, axis equal image, clip=false,
    axis lines=middle,
    xmin=-5,xmax=5,
    ymin=-5,ymax=5,
    restrict y to domain=-5:5,
    xtick={\empty},ytick={\empty},
    xlabel=$x$,ylabel=$y$,
    enlargelimits={abs=0.25cm},
    axis line style={latex-latex},
    xlabel style={at={(ticklabel* cs:1)},anchor=north west},
    ylabel style={at={(ticklabel* cs:1)},anchor=south west}
]

\addplot[blue, domain=-5:5] {x^3/(x^2 + 1)} node[anchor=west, pos=1, font=\footnotesize] {$y=\dfrac{x^{3}}{x^{2}+1}$};

\end{axis}

%Title for the plot of the second rational function.
\node[font=\bfseries, anchor=north, inner sep=0, align=center] at ($(current bounding box.south) +(0,-0.3)$)
{\mbox{An illustration of the continuity of} \\
\mbox{a rational function defined on \boldmath$\mathbb{R}$\unboldmath}};

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: why not use `\caption{title}` inside a `figure` environment, or `\captionof{figure}{title}` instead of this custom implementation?

Comment: @RunarTrollet No numbering here. Adelyn: I think I already answered this in your other question, where the text is placed relative to the axis instead of the bounding box.

Comment: @Torbjørn T.  I have the label `y=\frac{x^3}{x^2 + 1}`  for the plot on the Cartesian plane in this code.  (I do not have this label in the other post.)  I want the title for this plot to be centered, ignoring the horizontal width occupied by the label for the plot.

Comment: No, you don't have that label in the code in the question. And do the same as I did in the other question, add `name=ax1`, and place the node at `ax1.south` instead of `current bounding box.south`.

Comment: @Torbjørn T.  I just added `node[anchor=west, pos=1, font=\footnotesize] {$y=\dfrac{x^{3}}{x^{2}+1}$}`.  I apologize for the mistake.

Comment: @Torbjørn T.  Thanks.  The title is centered with respect to the `x`-axis with `ax1.south`.